# Creating VSIX package to install template to several project types?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to create a simple VSIX package to install a standard readme file that will then be available to add to all of our projects.

I am trying to find a way to get to install under project types of VB & C# along with project sub types of VB Web & C# Web.
I can accomplish this by creating a "C# or VB Item Template" project for each project type destination. This means that I would need 5 total projects, 1 for each destination and the VSIX project itself.

Since the file I'm installing is really project type independent is there a way to have one item template project that can have a manifest that would install under all the project types? Or a way to have 4 manifests in the one item template type?

The project should ultimately install under Visual Studio 2012 thru 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make an "Item Template project", export it (after creating the text file), and either copy the exported zip-file to your itemtemplates or let it automatically add it in the export wizard options.

Another way is creating a VSIX project. Add a Item Template project. Add the text file to the item template. Reference to the Item Template Project in the manifest of the VSIX. Build it and install it. You should now have the text file as an item template in your add item dialog.